# tomato plant rotting from the inside -- what's going on?

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes, insects, diseases

I have a hydroponic garden in a greenhouse in my yard.  Everything was going just great until today when I noticed that one of the 7 or so tomato plants (the biggest one in fact) was looking rather wilted.  Upon further examination I noticed some brown ooze coming from the inside!  I cut off the top branches where I saw this and continued to notice more and more until I finally removed the entire plant (out of concern for the others).

Does anyone know what could cause this?  I want to make sure my other plants are not in danger.  I've uploaded some pictures to help diagnose.

My first cut into the plant, notice the browning edges:

[My first cut into the plant, notice the browning edges http://a.yfrog.com/img620/5868/2enplp.jpg](http://a.yfrog.com/img620/5868/2enplp.jpg)

These yellow and brown leaves were from the bottom so maybe not a big deal?

[yellow and brown leaves were from the bottom http://a.yfrog.com/img614/5237/dqiyp.jpg](http://a.yfrog.com/img614/5237/dqiyp.jpg)

The inside of the plant close to the base.  ugghhh.

[The inside of the plant close to the base. http://a.yfrog.com/img614/3923/u47xo.jpg](http://a.yfrog.com/img614/3923/u47xo.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like Verticillium wilt.

Verticillium wilt is a soil-borne fungal disease that results in the yellowing, and eventual browning and death of foliage, particularly in branches closest to the soil. The wilt starts as yellow, V-shaped areas that narrow at the leaf margins. These yellow areas grow over time, turn brown, and then the leaf dies. Often, entire branches are infected.

Comment: based on some research it seems you're right.  i'm going to lessen the watering cycles and keep an eye on the other tomatoes.